# How do I authorize a controller action with Pundit if authorization depends on an instance variable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authorization, pundit

I have an `wedding` class with many `organizers`, and the resources are nested so, to view an event's organizers, I have to access: `/events/23/organizers`

The index controller for organizers is like so:

```
Class OrganizersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @wedding = Wedding.find(params[:wedding_id]
    @organizers = Organizer.where(wedding: @wedding)
  end
end
```

Trouble is, how do I allow pundit to authorize the index action for OrganizersController and only if for the `@wedding` in the instance, `@wedding.organizers.find(user: current_user).present?`?

They're two entirely different models, and the authorization of one depends on other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closest I've come to an answer is [this](https://github.com/elabs/pundit/issues/425#issuecomment-258406683).

> The way I usually do it, is to add a `list_organizers?` predicate to
>   the wedding policy and then:
>
> ```
> authorize(@wedding, :list_organizers?)
> ```
>
> It's not terribly elegant though.

If you find a better way to do this, please answer and I'll accept it as the better one.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that an `Organizer` belongs to a `Wedding` in which case you should have `@organizers = @wedding.organizers`.

However, to answer your question about pundit authorization, you should look at `scopes`. From here, you can return the weddings that the current user belongs to as an organizer.

You should also have a relation of the current user having many weddings as an organizer. So, you would have something like `current_user.weddings` since a user has many weddings through `organizer`.

Comment: Certainly, but a `current_user` has many `weddings`, and the only way to find out with `wedding` we're talking about is to look up `@wedding`. Furthermore, scopes would only limit the list of users. I want to disallow users from viewing the index of a wedding's organizers at `/weddings/3/organizers` unless the user is one of the organizers.

Answer (score -1):

Can you just add `authorize @wedding` in the index action of the organizations controller? Guessing your auth there is already setup to check if the user should have access to the wedding.